# A graph represented by the edges that do not follow from transitivity

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I am doing project with my group mates and we would like to introduce a notion. The notion is the following. We are working with a transitive directed graphs. Let $D$ be a transitive directed graph and we would like to define a graph which is the same graph but where only the arcs that do not follow from transitivity are displayed. What is the best way to formally define such notion?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ is *transitive*, if $E$ is a transitive binary relation, that is for any vertices $v$, $u$, and $w$ of $G$ if $(v,u)\in E$ and $(u,w)\in E$ then $(v,w)\in E$. Then we can reduce the set of edges of a finite graph $G$  to a set $E’$ such that the transitive closure of $E’$ is $E$, as follows. Each strongly connected component $C$ of $G$ is a clique, so we pick an arbitrary Hamiltonian cycle of $C$ and add its edges to $E’$. Next, let $V’$ be an arbitrary subset of $V$ such that $V’$ contains exactly one element of each strongly connected component of $G$. A subgraph $G’$ of $G$ induced by $V’$ is acyclic. Let’s call an edge $(v,w)$ of $G’$ *basic*, provided there is no vertex $u$ of $G’$ such that both $(v,u)$ and $(u,w)$ are edges of $G’$. It can be shown that for any edge $(v,w)$ of $G’$ there exists a sequence $v=u_1, u_2,\dots, u_{n-1}, u_n=w$ of vertices of $G’$ such that all edges $(u_i, u_{i+1})$ are basic. We add to $E’$ all basic edges of $G’$. The construction of the set $E’$ is finished and it provides that $E$  is the transitive closure of $E’$.